# How to handle Protocol Delegate when converting Objective-C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, protocols

I'm trying to convert a speech recognition code to Swift, Protocol defined in ViewController.h as:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<SpeechRecognitionProtocol>
{
    NSMutableString* textOnScreen;
    DataRecognitionClient* dataClient;
    MicrophoneRecognitionClient* micClient;
    SpeechRecognitionMode recoMode;
    bool isMicrophoneReco;
    bool isIntent;
    int waitSeconds;
}
```

I got stuck converting below function at ViewController.h:

```
micClient = [SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory createMicrophoneClient:(recoMode)
                                                       withLanguage:(language)
                                               withKey:(primaryOrSecondaryKey)
                                                          withProtocol:(self)];
```

This function is defined in the SpeechSDK.framework as:

```
@interface SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory : NSObject
/*
@param delegate The protocol used to perform the callbacks/events upon during speech recognition.
*/
+(MicrophoneRecognitionClient*)createMicrophoneClient:(SpeechRecognitionMode)speechRecognitionMode
                              withLanguage:(NSString*)language
                              withKey:(NSString*)primaryOrSecondaryKey
                              withProtocol:(id<SpeechRecognitionProtocol>)delegate;
@end
```

this protocol looks like this in my converted ViewController.Swift:

```
import UIKit    
protocol SpeechRecognitionProtocol {
    func onIntentReceived(result: IntentResult)
    func onPartialResponseReceived(response: String)
    func onFinalResponseReceived(response: RecognitionResult)
    func onError(errorMessage: String, withErrorCode errorCode: Int)
    func onMicrophoneStatus(recording: DarwinBoolean)
    func initializeRecoClient()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, SpeechRecognitionProtocol {
    var myDelegate: SpeechRecognitionProtocol?
```

finally I am calling this function inside ViewController.swift.  I am getting following error after withProtocol: **cannot convert value of type 'SpeechRecognitionProtocol.Protocol' to expected argument type 'SpeechRecognitionProtocol!'** :

```
func initializeRecoClient() {
    let language: String = "en-us"
    let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("settings", ofType: "plist")!
    let settings = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    let primaryOrSecondaryKey = settings?.objectForKey("primaryKey") as! String

    micClient = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.createMicrophoneClient(recoMode!,
                                               withLanguage: language, 
                                       withKey: primaryOrSecondaryKey,
                                withProtocol: SpeechRecognitionProtocol)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't declare the `SpeechRecognitionProtocol` yourself (not sure you added this just for demonstration purposes or whether your actually have that in your code). `SpeechRecognitionProtocol` is already declared in `SpeechRecognitionService.h` and available to Swift - this is the one you need to use.

The object implementing that protocol is `ViewController`. Assuming your `initializeRecoClient` is a method of that class, the call would need to look like:

```
micClient = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory
              .createMicrophoneClient(recoMode!,
                                      withLanguage: language, 
                                      withKey: primaryOrSecondaryKey,
                                      withProtocol: self)
```

The SpeechSDK API didn't choose a particularly good name for that factory method.
The `withProtocol` argument doesn't take the protocol object itself (as the name suggests), but the object implementing the protocol (obviously).

P.S.: Not sure what SpeechAPI version you use, I had to implement those Swift methods to make ViewController conform to `SpeechRecognitionProtocol`:

```
func onPartialResponseReceived(response: String!) {}
func onFinalResponseReceived  (response: RecognitionResult) {}
func onError                  (errorMessage: String!, 
                               withErrorCode errorCode: Int32) {}
func onMicrophoneStatus       (recording: Bool) {}
func onIntentReceived         (result: IntentResult) {}
```

Comment: I am totally new in iOS programming. so I removed top protocol declaration. but I am now getting **Type 'ViewController' does not conform to 'SpeechRecognitionProtocol' Class** error at the class ViewController line. I am using [this version of SpeechSDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt613452.aspx). Thanks

Comment: The SpeechRecognitionProtocol is from [here](https://www.projectoxford.ai/Files/Doc/Speech/ios/Protocols/SpeechRecognitionProtocol.html).

Comment: You need to take a look at the compiler output to see what protocol methods you are missing / got wrong. In Xcode this is the right-most button in the left column of the IDE. It has your build logs. Find the line with the error, then expand the log output using the button on the right (5 straight lines).

Comment: I did not see Build errors from Today but seen 'Build failed' red exclamation mark from yesterday. However, when I added parameters from your answer above (last code), the conform issue is gone.  Also, 'withProtocol: self' is working now without errors.

Comment: When I tested start button with Swift, it did not return transcribed value.  would this be because I converted variables at the top of ViewController class and Swift forced me to put initializers like `var textOnScreen: NSMutableString? = ""
    var micClient: MicrophoneRecognitionClient? = MicrophoneRecognitionClient()
    var recoMode: SpeechRecognitionMode? = SpeechRecognitionMode(rawValue: 0)
    var isMicrophoneReco: Bool = true
    var isIntent: Bool = false
    var waitSeconds: Int = 10`

Comment: YOU ARE LIFESAVER.  It is working now.  I will vote your answer when I am qualified to vote. Thanks.